Files or Folders Disappearing After Adding Them to .gitignore
I encountered an issue while working on an AI project using python. Whenever I add a file name or folder name to .gitignore, either the file disappears, or the folder's contents vanish. I'm not sure why this is happening.
i didnt get any proper solution anywhere

Are you using an IDE like VScode? There might be a setting, at least for vsc, that hides all gut ignore files. Or, are they disappearing in a different program, e.g. file explorer as well?

yes im using vscode.
thank you for your concern i got the solution

Open vscode, press ctrl+shift+p
open user setting(json)
set the "explorer.excludeGitIgnore" to false
"explorer.excludeGitIgnore": false
the above steps will solve the problem
